# Android 4.4 can use printer over Wi-Fi?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I searched on printing using wifi printer and I came to know that Android 4.4 can do this ([Android apps can now print any type of content over Wi-Fi](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html)) but I did not found any idea how to connect to wifi printer and give it command to print. Only I found that I can do this using Google cloud print (what if I want to use only wifi not the concept of Google cloud print). And provide me suggestion if it is possible (1. detect available wifi printer 2. connect to one 3.give command to print)

I found similar app [PrintBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.jsecurity.printbot&hl=en), PrinterShare , iCanPrint, but unable to guess "How they accomplish this?" I found some are using Google Cloud Print!

Something similar to Apple AirPrint

Answer (score 1):

As the link you provided mentions, "Printer manufacturers can use new APIs to develop their own print services — pluggable components that add vendor-specific logic and services for communicating with specific types of printers."

This means that the printer manufacturer has to supply an app to enable direct printing over WiFi. Without this, cloud-based services like Google Cloud Print are you only options.

Comment: Thanks onik for your suggestion! But I want to detect wifi printer and connect to it without printer manufacture app and google cloud prin

Comment: Similar to Apple Air print

Comment: This is not possible directly, it requires an app to act as a driver for the printer. Apple's solution has a defined protocol (AirPrint), and the printers you can use directly have to have AirPrint support. Google decided not to create a new standard for printers, but instead use a PC as an interface for the printer and handle the printer with the PCs drivers. The list of available printers is synced to your Google account, and this is why you can't use the printers directly without the cloud.

Comment: Thanks @onlik for your precious information! But what if I detect  all device connected to same wifi then fetch its' ip address and port and then send it to print using socket connection

Comment: Then you'd have to deal with the print protocols (LPR/LPD, JetDirect, RAW, IPP) directly, and that is independent of Android, and therefore out of the focus of this site.